# "Header Not Allowed By Access-Control-Allow-Headers In Preflight Response" (React App)

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs, request

**EDIT:** So I changed my code so that I'm handling the base64 encoding myself, which as one user noted, might be necessary.

Now I've encountered a new problem. I'm getting a CORS preflight error that looks like this:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/FlightInfo. Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Correct me if I'm mistaken: This would imply that the server does not allow "authorization" headers within HTTP requests (which doesn't make any sense, seeing as the docs explicitly tell me to encode the username and API key and pass them as an auth header).

I saw some other posts about this issue, but since I did not build the server, I can't go in and make the change that allows auth headers.

Any new ideas? Thank you so, so much!

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I'm building a React app that integrates with the [FlightAware API](https://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/).

I made a FlightAware component for handling HTTP requests to the API. I want to start with a simple request to get information about a given plane flight. Unfortunately, I keep getting a 401 unauthorized response despite providing my credentials via state.

(I know this isn't best practices, I'm just doing it temporarily to get the request working.)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Here's the code for the request:

```
componentDidMount() {  
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('ident', this.state.flightnum);
  form.append('howMany', '10');
  form.append('offset', '0');

  fetch('http://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/FlightInfo', {
    method: 'GET',
    auth: {
      user: this.state.user,
      pass: this.state.key
    },
    data: form
  })
  .then(result => {
    // do something...
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding your authentication data?  I see this in their API docs:
`it may be necessary to manually encode the "user:key" in base64 and send the result in the "Authorization" header as part of each HTTP request.`
You also need to ensure that fetch is sending the auth as part of the HTTP request headers.

Comment: I made these changes, and it helped progress my issue, but I ran into something new. Can you take a look? I updated my post. Thanks!